# How to fix column name is not in a groupBy laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am facing this error for the past 2-3 days. I hold this task to check this later in my free time. But still, I am getting the same error. Please help me to find the error. I am tired to check all solutions on google. But nothing works.

Error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'dating-app.messages.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `messages` group by `room_id` having `is_read` = 0) in file C:\xampp\htdocs\dating-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 692

Here is my query

```
$messages = Message::groupBy('room_id')->having('is_read', 0)->get();
return response()->json(['status' => true, 'message' => $messages]);`
```

Any solution appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because any column you use in a select statement must appear in the group by clause. So `select *` and `group by` don't get along. Remove `groupBy('room_id')` in your relationship and see how that goes.

Alternatively, disable MySQL strict mode by going into *config/database.php* and setting `strict => false` for MySQL, if you are using MySQL version >5.7.

[source](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-isnt-in-group-by)